# visual studio error message

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying hard to get rid of an error in visual studio. Firstly i got the problem which i am going to provide a snapshot in visual studio 2010. I tried to solve the problem by reinstalling .net framework, reinstalling visual studio 2010, cleaning the registry using ccleaner. But nothing worked. Then i shifted to visual studio 2012 but the same problem still continues. I will be very much thankful if someone can solve this issue. Please have a look at the snapshot. If none can solve it finally i have the last option and that is to format my laptop. [image]

My registry screen shot[image]

Comment: Did you check out that registry key and see if the message you are seeing is correct? Is there a property there with an empty name?

Comment: @AndrewBarber yaa i have checked that but didnot understand what to do

Comment: So what did you find when you checked that out?

Comment: @AndrewBarber i am providing a screenshot of that also

Comment: Ahhh! Check out the "(Default)" value; it's an empty string, it looks like. On mine, instead of the blank line, it says "(value not set)" (which is different from being set to empty). Not sure offhand why that would happen. You could fix it by backing up that whole key, restoring it, and removing the line from the .reg file that sets the value to that... but I'd hold on if you aren't comfortable with that...

Comment: You might also try just putting some text in there, after backing up just that key (and it's sub-key and all values). See if that works.